# Observer for Stream Switch

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am trying to add an observer for when the stream profile changes due to bandwidth, but I cant seem to find the right property to monitor.

I tried **AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent.switchBitrate** but that only returns the bandwidth that forced the switch, not the actual profile that was switched to or from.

Is there another property I should observe?

Thanks for any help.